# Matlab function of 2 variables in 2 different intervals

Tags: matlab

What is wrong with this code ? Without intervals and with only one Z function works perfectly, but I can't make it work.
Please help.

```
X=[0:0.01:1]
Y=[0:0.08:8]

[X,Y] = meshgrid(X,Y)
if X-0.08*Y <0.2
Z=1-(10*(X-0.08*Y)-1).^2
else
    Z=X*Y;
end

mesh(X,Y,Z);
title('a mesh plot of a function of two variables');
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put dots... You should consider dot multiplication. In top of it, you should add it in a for-loop (simple solution). There is another solution with less lines of code.

```
X-0.08*Y <0.2
```

gives always a "false" as result in a if-condition. You have to add a dot and loop.

```
X=[0:0.01:1]
Y=[0:0.08:8]    
[X,Y] = meshgrid(X,Y)    
Z=zeros(size(X));
for ii=1:size(Z,1)
  for jj=1:size(Z,2)
    if X(ii,jj)-0.08*Y(ii,jj) <0.2
      Z(ii,jj)=1-(10.*(X(ii,jj)-0.08.*Y(ii,jj))-1).^2;
    else
      Z(ii,jj)=X(ii,jj).*Y(ii,jj);
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to be more Matlab-ish and not use loops.

```
X=[0:0.01:1];
Y=[0:0.08:8];

[X,Y] = meshgrid(X,Y);

% Your else statement
Z=X*Y;

% The if-portion
[i,j]=find(X-0.08*Y <0.2);
Z(i,j)=1-(10*(X(i,j)-0.08*Y(i,j))-1).^2;

mesh(X,Y,Z);
title('a mesh plot of a function of two variables');
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
```

As suggested by Wli, you may want Z=X.*Y above if you desired element-by-element multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for inputting it. however X*Y won't give the same result as X.*Y, considering the if statement, I don't think he/she wants to do a matrix multiplication.

Comment: Yeah. I wasn't sure what was desired, so I left as is.